# How to make search and replace in content through php

Tags: content, the-content, post-content

I actually can show content and change content while displaying post. Problem is that I am using RSS importer and after importing I want to make search and replace and correct data imported because I know what is wrong with it.

```
    <?php
      add_action('pmxi_saved_post', 'post_saved', 10, 1);
      $my_post = array(
          "ID"           => $id,
          "post_content" => "1",
      );
     wp_update_post( $my_post );
    ?>
```

this is code I am using. Problem is that "post_content" does not change to value 1. Basically this code should change whatever is in post $id to value "1".

Why is this not working? I cannot figure it out for 2 hours now. All examples I have are based on change content while displaying but that does not change content IN database, only what is shown.

Comment: Would you update your answer to include the `pmxi_saved_post()` function? The code in your question is incomplete.

Comment: @DaveRomsey can I post link to Page with reference for this example? Actually this pxmi_saved_post is from plugin.  I think it is not relevant to this problem. I just want to save value. How?

Comment: Okay, I'd imagine it's just going to fire when saving an imported post. On second thought, what we need is your `post_saved` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation of [WP All Import](http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/advanced/action-reference/), the `pmxi_saved_post` action takes one parameter, `$id`, which is "the ID of the post/page/Custom Post Type that was just created."

So, your `post_saved()` callback should look like this:

```
add_action('pmxi_saved_post', 'wpse246838_post_saved', 10, 1);
function wpse246838_post_saved( $id ) {
    $my_post = array(
            "ID"           => $id,
            "post_content" => "1",
    );
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
}
```

Comment: You got it, @BSheep! Glad we were able to solve it!

Comment: PS: I'm surprised that the documentation would suggest such a general function name as `post_saved`. We should consider using a namespace, prefixing it or using anonymous functions, to avoid possible name collisions.

Comment: @birgire I agree, and that was lazy of me not to use something more appropriate. Updated the answer with the good old `wpse{question_id}_` prefix.